# Express: Render partially in each handler?

Tags: express, render, partial-views

I have a modest little site that uses Express and Pug. Every page has a navbar that contains the user's name drawn from a `user` parameter and the main content of the page is below which uses a `data` parameter. The main content is rendered from a template that extends the root template. Both need their own parameter to render properly.

Is there a way to partially render a view in each handler?

```js
var app = require('express')()
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    var userdata = '...'
    req.render('/index', {user: userdata}
    next() // the request is for /page
})

app.get('/page', (req, res, next) => {
   var moredata = '...'
   req.render('./page/index', {data: mroedata})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK that's not possible, but as an alternative, you can use [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals) to achieve something similar:

```
let userMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  let userdata = '...';
  res.locals.user = userdata;
  next();
});

app.use(userMiddleware);

// This can stay the same:
app.get('/page', (req, res, next) => {
   var moredata = '...'
   req.render('./page/index', {data: mroedata})
})
```

This is a middleware that will make the `user` variable available to all of your templates, which seems to me is what you want.

Instead of applying it globally, you can also use it for specific routes:

```
app.get('/page', userMiddleware, (req, res) => ...);
```